# Prettier next (2.6.0) + import order plugin @trivago/prettier-plugin-sort-imports Error Ignored unknown option { importOrderSeparation: true }

Tags: reactjs, prettier

I am moving from stable version of Prettier 2.0.5 to next version of Prettier 2.6.0 which is different from stable version. And got problem with @trivago/prettier-plugin-sort-imports plugin which was working with prettier 2.0.5 but does not with 2.6.0. As only 2.6.0 version supports this param https://prettier.io/docs/en/next/options.html#single-attribute-per-line. I have updated @trivago/prettier-plugin-sort-imports to last version and did migration to 3x according to https://github.com/trivago/prettier-plugin-sort-imports/blob/master/docs/MIGRATION.md

package.json

```
"scripts": {
"prettier-check": "prettier --check 'src/**/*.{css,scss,json,html,md,yml,yaml,js,jsx,ts,tsx}'",
},
"devDependencies": {
...
"@trivago/prettier-plugin-sort-imports": "^3.2.0",
"eslint-config-prettier": "^8.4.0",
"eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
"prettier": "prettier/prettier",
...
},
"eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "plugin:prettier/recommended",
      "plugin:cypress/recommended"
    ],
    "ignorePatterns": [
      "node_modules",
      "build",
      "openapi-client",
      "cypress/integration/examples",
      "!.storybook",
      ".github",
      ".ci",
      ".git"
    ],
    "rules": {
      "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": 0,
      "react/self-closing-comp": [
        "error",
        {
          "component": true,
          "html": true
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

.prettierrc

```
{
  "singleQuote": true,
  "semi": true,
  "tabWidth": 4,
  "printWidth": 100,
  "quoteProps": "consistent",
  "trailingComma": "es5",
  "importOrder": [
    "^@(assets|components|context|hooks|lib|pages|routes|services|styles|ui|utils)/?(.*)$",
    "^[./]"
  ],
  "importOrderSeparation": true,
  "importOrderParserPlugins": [
    "jsx",
    "typescript"
  ],
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": [
        "*.js",
        "*.jsx",
        "*.ts",
        "*.tsx",
        "*.json",
        "*.yml",
        "*.yaml",
        "*.md"
      ],
      "options": {
        "tabWidth": 2,
        "singleAttributePerLine": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

console says:

```
[warn] Ignored unknown option { importOrder: ["^@(assets|components|context|hooks|lib|pages|routes|services|styles|ui|utils)/?(.*)$", "^[./]"] }.
[warn] Ignored unknown option { importOrderSeparation: true }.
[warn] Ignored unknown option { importOrderParserPlugins: ["jsx", "typescript"] }.
```

Prettier does not see this plugin seems to be. Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 6):

You need to load the plugin on your Prettier config:

```js
{
  ...
  plugins: ['@trivago/prettier-plugin-sort-imports'],
}
```

For reference, see the [Using Plugin](https://prettier.io/docs/en/plugins.html#using-plugins) section on the Prettier docs.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem of prettier not seeing those things. I just use sort-imports plugin in vscode. IDK about the prettier integrated one though.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to install prettier in devDependencies

```
yarn add --dev prettier
```

Answer (score 0):

After installing the plugin, I had to uninstall the Prettier extension from VS Code, restart VS Code and then reinstall the extension before the plugin would work.

For reference, I am using the following versions...

- prettier v3.2.5
- Prettier VS Code Exension v10.1.0
- @trivago/prettier-plugin-sort-imports v4.3.0